# Difference between Recursion Tree & Binary Tree

Tags: graphs, binary-trees, recursion

What's the difference? is a Recursion tree private case of Binary tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree is a rooted tree where every internal node has at most two children.

A recursion tree is a rooted tree which traces the execution of a recursive procedure. It need not be binary.